# Discrete Uniform distribution from geometric samples.

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, sampling

Assume I sample *N* times from a geometric distribution with a known *p* i.e `samples=np.random.geometric(p, size=N)`. How can I calculate weights `p_prime(x)` using *p* in such I way that sampling with replacement (while giving more weight to less common values) results in a unifrom discrete distribution i.e. `np.random.choice(samples, size=N, replace=True, p=p_prime)`.

Comment: Is $N$ the same in both parts of the problem?

Comment: Yes, same number. The main ides is to get the function *f(x)* such that using `p_prime=[f(x) for x in samples]` yields something that is uniformly distributed.

Comment: So you take a sample size $N$ from the geometric distribution (with support on the positive integers) and then you do a weighted resample with replacement from your original sample also size $N$.  This clearly cannot give a discrete uniform distribution on the positive integers as there is no such distribution.  But it might be interesting to consider what you might get with weights proportional to $(1-p)^{-x}$

Comment: I am sorry if  I am not accurate with the math formalities. Yes, the idea is to have the resulting resample (up to `max(samples)`) have a uniform behavior.

Comment: Using $(1-p)^{-x}$ seems to work quite well!